# Reproduce a dataframe using expand.grid() in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I wonder if it might be possible to reproduce my `Data` below perhaps using `tidyr::expand_grid()`?

The variable `mot` can take any other values produced by `round(runif(8,1,4),1)` and is constant at each `time` value (just like `task`).

Variable `order` shows the `task` order across `time`. For example, for `id=1` at `time=1` `task` is `simple` (`s`) at `time=2` `complex` (`c`), thus `order` value is `s-c`.

I tried the following without success:

```
library(tidyr)
expand_grid(class=1:2, id=1:4, oder=c("s-c","c-s"),time=1:2, 
            task=c("simple","complex"))
```

```
Data ="
class id   order time DV  task      mot
1     1    s-c   1    ac  simple    1.5
1     1    s-c   1    bc  simple    1.5
1     1    s-c   2    ac  complex   2.3
1     1    s-c   2    bc  complex   2.3

1     2    c-s   1    ac  complex   3.9
1     2    c-s   1    bc  complex   3.9
1     2    c-s   2    ac  simple    4.0
1     2    c-s   2    bc  simple    4.0

2     3    s-c   1    ac  simple    2.7
2     3    s-c   1    bc  simple    2.7
2     3    s-c   2    ac  complex   1.2
2     3    s-c   2    bc  complex   1.2

2     4    c-s   1    ac  complex   2.8
2     4    c-s   1    bc  complex   2.8
2     4    c-s   2    ac  simple    1.1
2     4    c-s   2    bc  simple    1.1
"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rep()` with various combinations of `each`, and `times` makes:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(class=rep(1:2, each=8), 
       id=rep(1:4, each=4),
       order=rep(c("s-c", "c-s"), each=4, times=2),
       time=rep(1:2, each=2, times=4),
       DV=rep(c("ac", "bc"), each=1, times=8),
       task=rep(c("simple", "complex", "complex", "simple"), each=2, times=2),

       mot=rep(round(runif(8,1,4),1), each=2))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 16 × 7
>    class    id order  time DV    task      mot
>    <int> <int> <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
>  1     1     1 s-c       1 ac    simple    3  
>  2     1     1 s-c       1 bc    simple    3  
>  3     1     1 s-c       2 ac    complex   1.4
>  4     1     1 s-c       2 bc    complex   1.4
>  5     1     2 c-s       1 ac    complex   1.6
>  6     1     2 c-s       1 bc    complex   1.6
>  7     1     2 c-s       2 ac    simple    1.6
>  8     1     2 c-s       2 bc    simple    1.6
>  9     2     3 s-c       1 ac    simple    2.1
> 10     2     3 s-c       1 bc    simple    2.1
> 11     2     3 s-c       2 ac    complex   2.3
> 12     2     3 s-c       2 bc    complex   2.3
> 13     2     4 c-s       1 ac    complex   3.7
> 14     2     4 c-s       1 bc    complex   3.7
> 15     2     4 c-s       2 ac    simple    2.4
> 16     2     4 c-s       2 bc    simple    2.4
> ```

Comment: Thanks! A quick follow-up! Say I want to add a column called `score`. For all `DV=ac` rows, I want `score` column to take a random value from `ac = round(rbeta(8,2,3),1)` and for 
all `DV=bc` rows, a random value `bc = round(rnorm(8,19),1)`. Is this possible?

Comment: You could add a score like that as a second step like `df$score<-0; df[df$DV=="ac",]$score<-round(rbeta(8,2,3),1); df[df$DV=="bc",]$score<-round(rnorm(8,19),1)`

Comment: Is there any way to make his expandable as a function? For instance, say I want 5 `id`s rather than 4 as currently shown. Can the rest of the data.frame follow the rhythm?

Comment: I tried the following without success: `n_class = 2;
n_time = 2;
n_subj = 5;
n_row = n_subj^n_time;

df <- data.frame(class=rep(1:n_class, each=n_row/n_class), 
                 id=rep(1:n_subj, each=n_subj),
                 order=rep(c("s-c", "c-s"), each=n_subj, times=n_time),
                 time=rep(1:n_time, each=n_time, times=n_subj),
                 DV=rep(c("ac", "bc"), each=1, times=n_row/n_class),
                 task=rep(c("simple", "complex", "complex", "simple"), each=n_time, times=n_time),
                 mot=rep(round(runif(n_row/n_class,1,4),1), each=n_time))`

Comment: This is getting more complex, for example, if there were 5 ids, would the 5th id be in class 1 or 2? There is an another rep() attribute `length.out=`, using that you can make a longer repeating pattern - which is either recycled or cut short by length.out.